# Is it worth worrying about propagation delay differences when dealing with relatively slow protocols like I2C @ 400kHz?

Tags: i2c, delay, timing

At the moment I'm working on a system which will use a 400KHz I2C bus. The bus wires (SCL, SDA) are different lengths by a few cm, so the delay between them will be in picosecond to nanosecond range - I don't think I need to worry about this but am I misguided?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For anything under 50MHz, difference in trace lengths like that wouldn't be a concern.

Comment: I referred to 'trace lengths' but it just sank in you said 'wires'. Propagation delays still won't be a problem with wire, just don't coil up the excess, that would give you unwanted inductance which could take the nice sharp edges off the logic signals.