# Timing differences with a 27 MHz data clock

Tags: pcb, timing

I'm considering using a chip which outputs 8-bit data on a 27 MHz clock. The data will go from the chip to a FPGA, a distance of a few cm max. Do I need to be concerned about timing differences between traces on a PCB, and if so, how can I mitigate these? I've often seen motherboards with traces in small coil shapes, presumably to act as little delay lines.

Comment: I was going to mark this as a duplicate, but I decided that this one is different enough (faster and parallel) to not mark your [question about skew on 400kHz I2C](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/5526/8) as a dupe.

Comment: I'd also be looking at terminating these lines correctly to minimize reflections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leon is right, it probably doesn't matter for 27MHz signals on traces that are only a few cm long.

However, you can mitigate skew by making the trace lengths equal.  If you've got the time to ask a question about it, and you have the board space, why wouldn't you want to do this?  There's very little reason to build skew into your circuit.  Make little 45<sup>o</sup> wiggles in the traces to make the distances the same and avoid building in reflections.  This makes equalizing the trace length easy if your PCB program doesn't do it for you.   Or, you can use rounded traces, but keeping the trace lengths equal gets more difficult.

Here's a PCB which uses LVDS.  There's an NI board connected to this one through a 2m, 100-pin ribbon cable, and the other side of the LVDS transcievers connects to a parallel bus, so there are many sources of skew.  Why not eliminate the PCB as a source of skew?
[image: LVDS transciever with squiggles]
Note: On this PCB, the paired traces are supposed to be coupled together.  In a non-differential bus, running pairs like this will give you really bad cross-talk.

Comment: If I recall correctly, getting equal-length traces (even with differential pairs) is a few clicks in Altium Designer.

Comment: And Mentor Graphics Expedition PCB, which this board was designed in.

Answer (score 2):

At 27 MHz any differences in track length over a few cm will have a negligible effect. Try doing some calculations involving the speed of light, allowing for the velocity factor.

Comment: I figured I need to do this, but electricity doesn't travel at the speed of light through copper (it's slower.) Anyway, I think it should be okay, I just need a little reassurance.

Comment: Travels at `v=c/sqrt(permittivity)`, or around 0.4c.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the good answers by others, there's still things you can do if you've got functional failures due to trace mismatch on your board (though at 27 MHz, there's not much to worry about). Most modern FPGAs from Xilinx (and maybe Altera, not sure) have reconfigurable delay element inside of the I/O pin so you could adjust with very fine resolution when the signal is captured. Look for the 'IDELAY' and 'ODELAY' primitives.